# Flutter: Get rendered text from content

Tags: dart, flutter

This the content of a post (wordpress) with the API plugin for WP (JSON):

```
"content": {
   "rendered": "<p>Content post.<\/p>\n", <---- I want retrieve this
   "protected": false
}
```

How can I do it? (Using with your example -> https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('http://***********:88/WordPress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/65');
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

  return new Post.fromJson(responseJson);
}

class Post {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final String imagen;

  Post({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.imagen});


factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return new Post(
    title: json['content'].toString(),
    body: json['content'].toString(),
  );
}
```

My problem in my app:
[image]

Comment: What part causes troubles?

Comment: I have updated the post, 
My problem is that you are selecting everything that contains title.

I just want to take what it contains title -> rendered -> only text

Comment: What do you mean by "only text"? What about `title: json['content']['rendered'] as String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
body: json['content'].toString(),
```

But if you just want the `rendered` property then it should probably be this:

```
body: json['content']['rendered'].toString(),
```

However since it has HTML, you probably will also want something like [flutter_html_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_view) to render the HTML.